# How to download and join a movie in vlc

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, vlc

I know how to download a streaming movie with VLC but I have a problem. When it comes to a movie that comes in sequencial links like movie_part_1 , movie_part_2, etc, how can I download all of the parts and joint them together?
Thank you!

Comment: what codec are these parts in ?   from the command line ffmpeg can stitch together video clips

Comment: Mpg format is the type.

Answer (score 1):

multiple mpg files can be combined into one output file using command line tool  ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.mpg|input2.mpg|input3.mpg" -c copy output.mpg
```

see details at  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: And how about downloading them...?

Comment: depends on which URL ... do you have an example ?

Comment: URL is a big https one... At the end has the ==1.ts, 2.ts...etc

Comment: Till now I managed to download on windows enviroment with the folloing batch file all the parts with vlc. Could these parts been joint together at the end ?

for /l %%x in (152, 1, 250) do (

vlc.exe --play-and-exit -vvv https://media02-SOME_LONG_STRING==_%%x.ts --sout=file/ps:C:\Users\Vagelis\Desktop\dir\part_%%x.mpg
 
)

Comment: I suggest you checkout the tool ...  youtube-dl